# Show $\gamma(I)$ is a regular parametrized curve in $S$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $U={(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | u>0,v>0}$ be the open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\sigma:U\to\mathbb{R}^3$, $\sigma(u,v)=(u^2,2v,1/v)$

I've shown that $S=\sigma(U)$ is a parametrized surface in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0,\infty)$ and $\gamma:I\to \mathbb{R}^3$, $\gamma(t)=\sigma(t^2+1,2t)=((t^2+1)^2,2(2t),1/(2t))$
Show $\gamma(I)$ is a regular parametrized curve in $S$

Would it be enough to show that $\gamma$ is smooth, injective and regular, to conclude the above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the derivative $\gamma'(t)=(4t(t^2+1),4,-1/2t^2)$, which clearly is never the zero vector $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: But would that make it a paramatrized curve in $S$? Doesn't that just imply it's regular?

Comment: it is regular on the surface, save at $t=0$ because there, it hasn't defined derivative as well as $\gamma(0)$